# Wildcard erroring out on import in Node.js

Tags: node.js, import, syntax

I keep getting an error on an import statement:

```
import * as foo from './bar.mjs';
```

Here is the code that I am testing...

```
import  *  as foo from './bar.mjs';

console.log(foo.hello());
console.log(`${foo.next()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(`${foo.next()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(`${foo.default()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(`${foo.next()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(`${foo.next()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(`${foo.next()} ${foo.squared()}`);

console.log(foo.meaning);
```

Here is the error...

```
$ node testMod.mjs
/home/user/node-web-dev/testMod.mjs:1
import  *  as foo from './bar.mjs';
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Can anyone shed some light on why the wildcard '*' in the import statement is erroring out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node 10 requires the `--experimental-modules` argument to use the ESM module loader.

```
node --experimental-modules testMod.mjs
(node:80220) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
[Module] { blah: 2, test: 1 }
```

The current versions of Node (16/18) have much better ESM support so I would start there.

Comment: thank you. I will be doing a lot of reading on the ESM module loader, now.